# How show or hide div genered dynamiclly by PHP using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that is dynamically generated and populated by PHP. In a part of the form I have a for loop that, depending on the number of records in the database, it repeats. In this part I have a choice in radio button and I want that depending on the choice I hide a div and show another one and vice versa.

Here's the PHP and JQuery code I made.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $data['partsCount']; $i++) :
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="service_id">Serviço</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="service" value="<?php echo $data['services'][$i]->name; ?>" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="type_id">Tipo</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" value="<?php echo $data['types'][$i]->name; ?>" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="amount">Quantidade</label>
                        <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $data['parts'][$i]->amount; ?>" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="value">Valor Unitário</label>
                        <input type="text" name="value" id="value" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($data['value_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $data['parts'][$i]->value; ?>" disabled />
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $data['value_err']; ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="value">Valor Total</label>
                        <input type="text" name="total" value="<?php echo $data['parts'][$i]->valueTotal; ?>" class="form-control" disabled />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="status1" name="status[]" class="custom-control-input" value="2" checked>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="status1">Aprovado</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="status2" name="status[]" class="custom-control-input" value="3">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="status2">Reprovado</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rejected-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="row my-4">
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="desc">Motivo para a não aprovação do orçamento</label>
                    <textarea name="reject_notes[]" id="editor1" class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($data['text_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="accepted-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="row my-4">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label for="data_out">Data de Entrega</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg date">
                            <input type="text" name="delivery_date[]" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker<?php echo $i; ?>" />
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="desc">Caminho para as artes</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="path_files[]" id="">
                    <label for="desc">Caminho para a PM/RM</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="path_pm[]" id="">
                    <label for="desc" class="mt-3">Descritivo e orientações de criação</label>
                    <textarea name="accept_notes[]" id="editor2" class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($data['text_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endfor;
            ?>
```

JQuery

```
    $('#status1').click(function () {
    $(this).next('div[id^=accepted]').show('slow');
    $(this).next('div[id^=rejected]').hide('slow');
  });

  $('#status2').click(function () {
    $(this).next('div[id^=accepted]').hide('slow');
    $(this).next('div[id^=rejected]').show('slow');
  });
```

With this code when I choose one of the options it influences all the parts of the code that are created by the loop. I need you to influence the block that is referent

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if so then you have to:
1. Generate an individual ID for each div or object 2. simply echo this into the Js file with which the div or object can be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use relative paths. Put the listener on all `class` matches, and you had the rest already complete.

Your radios can keep their IDs for the `labelfor` attribute but they need to be unique, so use the iterator for that `$i`. Give them a class to separate the two. I chose `status-a` and `status-r` - we'll use those in the listener

```
<div class="status-a custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="status-a<?php echo $i;?>" name="status[]" class="custom-control-input" value="2" checked> 
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="status-a<?php echo $i;?>">Aprovado</label>
</div>
<div class="status-r custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="status-r<?php echo $i;?>" name="status[]" class="custom-control-input" value="3">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="status-r<?php echo $i;?>">Reprovado</label>
</div>
```

Now you can use relative paths based on the class

```
$('.status-a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div[id^=accepted]').show('slow');
  $(this).next('div[id^=rejected]').hide('slow');
});

$('.status-b').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div[id^=accepted]').hide('slow');
  $(this).next('div[id^=rejected]').show('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem that way

PHP Block

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="status-a custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="status-a<?=$i?>" name="status-<?=$i?>[]" class="custom-control-input" value="2" checked>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="status-a<?=$i?>">Aprovado</label>
        </div>
        <div class="status-b custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="status-b<?=$i?>" name="status-<?=$i?>[]" class="custom-control-input" value="3">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="status-b<?=$i?>">Reprovado</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rejected-<?=$i?>" class="row my-4">
    <div class="col">
        <label for="desc">Motivo para a não aprovação do orçamento</label>
        <textarea name="reject_notes[]" id="editor1" class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($data['text_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="accepted-<?=$i?>" class="row my-4">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="data_out">Data de Entrega</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg date">
                <input type="text" name="delivery_date[]" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" id="datetimepicker<?php echo $i; ?>" />
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <label for="desc">Caminho para as artes</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="path_files[]" id="">
        <label for="desc">Caminho para a PM/RM</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="path_pm[]" id="">
        <label for="desc" class="mt-3">Descritivo e orientações de criação</label>
        <textarea name="accept_notes[]" id="editor2" class="form-control form-control-lg <?php echo (!empty($data['text_err'])) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Block

```
let partsCount = document.getElementById('data-count').value;
  console.log(partsCount);
  for (let i = 0; i < partsCount; i++) {
    $('#status-a' + i).click(function () {
      $('#accepted-' + i).show('slow');
      $('#rejected-' + 1).hide('slow');
      console.log('Click: accepted-' + i);
    });

    $('#status-b' + i).click(function () {
      $('#accepted-' + i).hide('slow');
      $('#rejected-' + i).show('slow');
      console.log('Click: rejected-' + i);
    });
  }
```

Thanks for helping